# How to send message to extension made request?

Tags: powershell, http, google-chrome-extension, request

I'm trying to pass a string to my extension that I created via powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` and then the extension returns a result.

My powershell script trying to call extension passing `test` value

```
# Sets extension ID and message endpoint address
$extensionId = 'lglkkngdjbdkecenknlhdmcopijeiohd';
$messageEndpoint = '127.0.0.1';    
# Creates the request body as a JSON object
$body = @{
  data = 'test'
};

# Makes an HTTP POST request
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $messageEndpoint -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{
  'x-extension-id' = $extensionId
}
```

In my extension's `manifest.json` file, I set `externally_connectable`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Quality",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "permissions": ["runtime"],
    "description": "Quality",
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
            "js": ["index.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the `index.js` file I put the part where the extension receives the messages

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log('Message received:', request);
    
  // Process the message here...
  sendResponse({
    data: 'Message processed successfully'
  });
});
```

When I run the powershell command I get this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:11 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $messageEndpoint -Body $body -Con ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWe 
   bRequestCommand
```

Even putting IPV4 instead of 127.0.0.1 gives the same error. How can I call the extension by making a request?

Comment: That's absolutely not [how externally_connectable works](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage). Also, there's no way for an extension to listen on an HTTP port for connections, it can only connect to an external port. Try using nativeMessaging API instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a native messaging sample.
I used Python this time.
This tutorial will help you to install native messaging.
[How to make Chrome Extension 62 Native messaging](https://youtu.be/VmdW78mExWY)

[image]

`server.reg` depends on the development folder `C:\Users\norio\hoge`, so you need to rewrite it according to your environment.

You need to install the psutil module.
[image]

How to associate Python files.
[image]

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
const main = () => {
  console.log("main")
  const port = chrome.runtime.connectNative("server");
  console.log(port)
  port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    console.log("Received: " + message);
    port.postMessage("Message processed successfully");
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  main();
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  main();
});
```

server.json

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "description": "Deleting this key will result in an error.",
  "path": "server.py",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://<Your Extension ID>/"
  ]
}
```

server.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\server]
@="C:\\Users\\norio\\hoge\\server.json"
```

server.py

```py
import os
import psutil
import sys
import json
import struct
from http.server import HTTPServer
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler


def getMessage():
    rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
    messageLength = struct.unpack("@I", rawLength)[0]
    message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(messageLength).decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(message)


def encodeMessage(messageContent):
    encodedContent = json.dumps(messageContent).encode("utf-8")
    encodedLength = struct.pack("@I", len(encodedContent))
    return {"length": encodedLength, "content": encodedContent}


def sendMessage(encodedMessage):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage["length"])
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage["content"])
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()


class class1(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers["content-length"])
        postData = format(self.rfile.read(content_length).decode("utf-8"))
        sendMessage(encodeMessage(postData))
        html = getMessage()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(html.encode())


pidFile = "server.pid"
lastPid = -1

if os.path.isfile(pidFile):
    with open(pidFile) as f:
        lastPid = int(f.read())

pid = os.getpid()

with open(pidFile, mode="w") as f:
    f.write(str(pid))

try:
    p = psutil.Process(lastPid)
    pyFile = os.path.basename(p.cmdline()[1])
    if (pyFile == "server.py"):
        p.terminate()

except Exception as err:
    pass

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 80

server = HTTPServer((ip, port), class1)

server.serve_forever()
```

client.ps1

```
# Sets message endpoint address
$messageEndpoint = '127.0.0.1';    
# Creates the request body as a JSON object
$body = @{
  data = 'test'
};

# Makes an HTTP POST request
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri $messageEndpoint -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{
}
```

Comment: it almost worked, but it opens the python file with the vscode editor, should I set it in the properties to open it with another file?

Comment: @sYsTeM, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for software running outside the browser to communicate with a Chrome extension is to use [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/). You would need to create an application called a native messaging host that implements the protocol described on that page, and you would need to connect to it from your background page*, not your content script. If you don't want to implement the host in a compiled language, your host could be a simple batch file that runs a JavaScript file in Node.js.

There are three problems with your current approach:

- `Invoke-WebRequest` is for communicating with an HTTP server. Chrome and its extensions are not servers. There are a number of ways a PowerShell script could communicate with your native messaging host, and having the host set itself up as an HTTP server is certainly one option.
- `"externally_connectable"` is for allowing scripts from a Web page running within Chrome to communicate with your extension. It's not needed for things like PowerShell scripts running outside of Chrome.
- `"content_scripts"` is for running code on a Web page being shown in Chrome, and will not have access to most extension APIs. You'll need to connect to your host from a background page*.

* Assuming you stick with Manifest Version 2. Manifest Version 3 replaces background pages with service workers.